# Want to append "_valid" at the end where ever i find the pattern "is_tokenized" in my column names

Tags: shell

I have and INPUT as mentioned below:

```
realmid,
passwordkdf,
lastLoadTime,
is_tokenized_login,
is_tokenized_email
```

And i am expecting an output like where ever is see a pattern "`is_tokenized`" on that particular column at the end I want to append "`_valid`".

Hence my output will look something like this:

```
realmid,
passwordkdf,
lastLoadTime,
is_tokenized_login_valid,
is_tokenized_email_valid
```

Answer (score 1):

This sed one-liner should help:

```
sed '/is_tokenized/s/,\?$/_valid&/' file
```

with your example:

```
kent$  cat f
realmid,
passwordkdf,
lastLoadTime,
is_tokenized_login,
is_tokenized_email

kent$  sed '/is_tokenized/s/,\?$/_valid&/' f
realmid,
passwordkdf,
lastLoadTime,
is_tokenized_login_valid,
is_tokenized_email_valid
```

### Update, in single line case:

If all those CSVs are in single line, you can do this with awk :

```
awk -F, -v OFS="," '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/is_tokenized/)$i=$i"_valid"}7' file
```

Comment: I have problem as my data is all in single line separated by  comma.It is something like this:

realmid,passwordkdf,lastLoadTime,is_tokenized_login,is_tokenized_email

Comment: @sampatkumar but you wrote in question in separated lines, see my edit history. http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34592425/revisions

Comment: @sampatkumar, any way, check the update in my answer. Also pls edit your question, to provide right example.

Comment: sure kent.. apologize for the mistake.

Comment: The single line case looks like it can be `sed 's/is_tokenized[^,]\+/&_valid/g'`

Comment: @Kent 
I have one more input where i am unable to get to the output .

Please use the below input and find the "is_tokenized" and add "_valid" to the end and also insert the value as shown below OUTPUT form:

INPUT: realmid,passwordkdf,lastLoadTime,is_tokenized_log_in,is_tokenized_email

OUTPUT: realmid,passwordkdf,lastLoadTime,log_in,is_tokenized_log_in_valid,email,is_tokenized_email_valid

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/is/{$0=$0"_valid"}{gsub(/in,_valid/,"in_valid,")}1' file
realmid,
passwordkdf,
lastLoadTime,
is_tokenized_login_valid,
is_tokenized_email_valid
```